# Getting length of hasMany association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following Models defined in my Ember project (project created with ember-cli 0.2.3)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Game = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    geekRating: DS.attr('number')
});

Game.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        { id: "1", title: "Catan", description: "Catan the game", geekRating: "5.65"}
    ]
});

export default Game;

import DS from 'ember-data';

var OwnedGame = DS.Model.extend({
    rating: DS.attr('number'),
    plays: DS.hasMany('gamePlay'),
    game: DS.belongsTo('game', {async: true}),
    playCount: function() {
        return this.get('plays.length')
    }.property('plays')
});

OwnedGame.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        { id: "1", rating: "8.25", game: "1"}
    ]
});

export default OwnedGame;

import DS from 'ember-data';

var GamePlay = DS.Model.extend({
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    ownedGame: DS.belongsTo('ownedGame', {async: true})
});

GamePlay.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: "1", date: "2015-01-01", ownedGame: "1"},
        {id: "2", date: "2015-02-01", ownedGame: "1"}
    ]
});

export default GamePlay;
```

And then in my owned-games/index.hbs

```
<h1>My Games</h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Your Rating</th>
            <th>Geek Rating</th>
            <th>Plays</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each game in this}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{game.game.title}}</td>
                <td>{{game.game.description}}</td>
                <td>{{game.rating}}</td>
                <td>{{game.game.geekRating}}</td>
                <td>{{game.playCount}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to display the length of the `plays` for an `OwnedGame` with a computed property. Note that as you can see I'm using Fixture Data so not sure if this might be a limitation. I'm not getting any errors, and the list of OwnedGames displays just fine (just 1 of them for now). I'm getting 0 for the size of plays.

I've read other similar threads about this issue, and I believe I have the code correct, but not sure why it isn't working.

UPDATE:

I also tried doing this on each iteration of game:

```
{{#each play in game.plays}}
    {{play.date}}
{{/each}}
```

And I get no output.

Update #2:

I created all the necessary code to view a list of GamePlay's. The size is 0 until I visit the list of GamePlay's. Then if I go back to my list of OwnedGames, the length of GamePlay's is now 2, which is accurate. So I think I just need to figure out how to get the computed property to query for the data?

Comment: Are you able to iterate through `game.plays` in your template?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet because that isn't really what I want to do. I do know that when I look at the data in the ember inspector, there are 0 plays. But I think that is just because of the lazy loading (async).

Comment: @Moogs see my update to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `hasMany` relationship, you have two options on how to go about fetching the side loaded data.

**First option** is to specify what `plays` records you want by specifying an array with `game-play` ids on the `owned-game` fixture. This will make another request for `game-play` automatically for you and populate your model asynchronously.

```
App.OwnedGame.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: 1, rating: 8.25, game: 1, plays: [1,2]}
    ]
});
```

**Second option** is to manually make a second request to fetch `game-play` data, which will populate the `plays` property of `owned-game` asynchronously.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
       return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
           gamePlay: this.store.find('game-play'),
           ownedGame: this.store.find('owned-game')
       });
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('model', model.ownedGame);
    }
});
```

**http://emberjs.jsbin.com/woruqugida/1/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: I went with your first suggestion. It was the least invasive. Will this take care of itself when I replace the Fixture Data with real data? Or would the returned JSON also have to return an array of ID's to work correctly?

Comment: @Gregg the fixtures simulate real data, so the server can either return a list of `plays` ids, or better, just include the full `plays` payload array in place of the ids.

Comment: @Gregg no prob. It takes a lot of practice to get the hang of ember and appreciate all the work it does for you.